# How to maximize the amount of money at the end of the week?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, finance, operations-research

This is the statement of my problem:

> A new financial product is made so that if you invest X thousands of pounds a day, and a third more the next day, the third day we would recover triple of the investment from the first day. How should we invest 100,000 pounds during a full week for us to have the maximum money at the end of the week?

My attempt:

My decision variables are: $x_1$ = amount of pounds (in thousands of pounds) invested the first day, $x_2$ = amount of pounds invested the third day, $x_3$ = amount of pounds invested the fifth day.

It is supposed that you can reinvest the benefit you obtain during the week, and you can not invest more than the indicated (for instance, the second day you only invest $4/3x_1$).

Therefore, the objective would be: $3x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 - \frac{7}3(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$ discounting to profit what is spent.

And my restrictions: $0 \leq x_1 \leq 100$, $0 \leq x_2 \leq 100 - \frac{7}3x_1 + 3x_1$ and $0 \leq x_3 \leq 100 - \frac{7}3x_1+3x_1-\frac{7}3x_2+3x_2$

Could anyone check my solution and tell me if it is correct, or should I change anything?

Thank you!

Comment: In a seven day week, wouldn’t it be possible to invest everyday until the 4th day? In that we’d have decision variables for four days and the relationship between each investment is (say the first day is on sunday) $x_1 + (1/3)x_1$ for first day, $x_2 + (1/3)x_2$ for the second day and so on, with returns being the $3(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer below. According to the statement of my problem, the second day you can only invest the third part from the day one, and the same applies to days 4 and 6. So I believe in your second answer, we would only have variables $x_1$ to $x_4$.

Comment: It doesn’t say anywhere in your problem statement that you’re not allowed to invest on multiple days, just the behaviors of the investment if you invested on that day, in that you’re able to invest on two neighboring days and they’ll be independent of each other (minus the resources) and the mentioned behavior will apply to both of them

Comment: Now I understand your point of view, alright. But then, why don't you have $x_6$ and $x_7$? I don't get why we can assume that our returns are delayed by two days in the statement.

Comment: because we’re limited to a week timeframe, the returns on those days would happen during the overlap into the next week which goes against the final statement in given problem of “How should we invest 100,000 pounds during a full week for us to have the maximum money at the end of the week?”. We’d only $x_6$ and $x_7$ if the problem was asking for maximizing investments in a timespan that’s more than a week

Comment: In other words, we must assume that week ends on $x_7$. Any investments we make for $x_6$ we’d never get because there exists no day to make something like $3x_6$ possible because that would be sunday of the next week (if we assume $x_1$ started on a sunday)

Comment: My belief is that if you invested all in days 1-2, 3-4,5-6 you’ll get more than 10x return. If you increased the frequency to daily (1 through 5, with return 3 through 7) you’ll get some 9x return depending on investment structure of days 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation is over-predicting/assuming behaviors about the investments in that you’re only looking to invest on every third day. Since this is a seven day week in which our returns are delayed by two days, it’s possible to invest everyday like so:

$$\max z = 3(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4+x_5) - (1/3)(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)$$

Subject to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i + (1/3)x_i \le 100$$

$$x_i \ge 0\quad\forall i\in[1,\ldots,5]$$

---

If we can reinvest our earnings like you mentioned, then it would go like the following:

$$\max z = 3(x_4+x_5) - (1/3)x_5$$

Subject to:

$$x_1 \le 100$$
$$x_2 \le 100 - (4/3)x_1$$
$$x_3 \le 100 + 3x_1 - (4/3)x_2$$
$$x_4 \le 100 + 3x_2 - (4/3)x_3$$
$$x_5 \le 100 + 3x_3 - (4/3)x_4$$

$$x_i \ge 0\quad\forall i\in[1,\ldots,5]$$

Comment: Put this into a LP solver, and got the following: $z=1638.095$ with $x_1= 42.857$, $x_2=42.857$, $x_3=171.429$, $x_4=0$, and $x_5=614.286$

Comment: $z$ would the same in both solutions, I guess.

Comment: I put your model into an LP solver and got $z=362.962963$ with $x_1=100$, $x_2 = 166.6666667$, and $x_3=277.7777778$. So they're not really at all the same tbh

Comment: I meant that the objective is different in the formulation where you consider reinvesting the earnings, why are there no $x_1$ to $x_3$?

Comment: Because we're reinvesting them in the full amount, we lose their values as they're placed into $x_4$ and $x_5$, because if we get their returns in the mid-week and still have time to reinvest, thus we should.

The only returns we're getting is the full reinvestment from $x_4$ and $x_5$ since they're the only variables we cannot reinvest back into the model

Comment: Having $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ in the objective function wouldn't make sense in a reinvestment model as you don't get to keep their values after the model is done because their values were placed into other variables